# Delete line containing specific text... e.g. delete all lines containing "Created by..."

Tags: regex, xcode

I am doing a cleanup though a XCode project of mine and wanted to remove all instances of the created by comment automatically placed in the header when using XCode and creating new files. I would just go through and delete them all manually but that would take a really long time seeing as there are over 900 files containing this created by comment.

I have tried using the find and replace but that is not working as it only deletes the // Created by [name] on... bit and thats it, the date is left behind because it is not part of the text I entered in on find so it assumes I don't want to delete the date part. I just need a way to find all strings containing Created by, and perform a mass delete on them across the whole project, the entire line containing them.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode creates each file using the next pattern:

```swift
//
//  Filename.swift
//  Target
//
//  Created by Name on 24/02/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Companyname. All rights reserved.
//
```

You could use remove the `// Created by Name on DD/MM/YYYY.` and a new line using the next regular expression:

```
(\/\/\s\s\b\b(Created by Name on )(([1-2][0-9])|([1-9])|(3[0-1]))\/.((1[0-2])|([1-9]))\/[0-9]{4}.)\n
```

Put it into the Xcode's `Navigator/Find Navigator/Replace/Regular Expression` (or simply press cmd+4)

[image]

[More details on regular expressions](https://regexr.com/4uuub)